# How to "cast" filetype (HTML/JS/PHP) on temporary buffer to load plugins & configurations

Tags: filetype

I'm using neovim with vim-plug.

I do some webapp testing where I want to see the raw HTML/JS/PHP/etc of a page. This can be done with something like `curl example.com > tmp.html; nvim tmp.html` and nvim  would load plugins and commands to be used on HTML files. However, I'd rather not save & open files like that for every page.

What I usually do is use python-requests for testing. The python script would `GET`/`POST` a page and output the HTML *and* some extra python output. For example:

get.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests

print("testing...")

p = requests.get("http://example.com")
print(p.text)

print("DONE")
```

terminal

```
$ ./get.py | nvim -
```

(It can be as simple as printing some extra text or extra processing with `grep`. Non-HTML output is expected.)

When there's non-HTML output, I don't get HTML syntax-highlighting & HTML plugins aren't loaded. These should all be formatted in a temporary buffer for rapid testing.

I can make an `augroup` to run some commands but I'm not sure plugins would be loaded. Some plugins may be loaded but certain filetype-specific functions of the plugins don't work (eg Coc's coc-prettier).

How can I "cast" the filetype to HTML/JS/PHP/etc and have nvim load everything that should be loaded when an HTML file is opened?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is just force the filetype:

```
vim <(script | ...) -c 'set filetype=html'
```

Or inside vim

```
:set filetype=javascript
```

(For example)